# How to save Combobox and checkedlistbox into mysql php using vb

Tags: mysql, vb.net

i'm using vb 2017. I try to save combobox value and checkedlistbox item into database. The database table only shows "System.Data.DataRowView" for combobox and "System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox+ObjectCollection" for checkedlistbox. Can anyone help me? I'm using mysql phpmyadmin for database. This is the codes i'm using below. it show no error. But the selected item value has not show in database table.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim constr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=login;port=3306;password=root123;SslMode=none"
Dim conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(constr)
Dim result As Integer
'If True Then
Try
    conn.Open()
    With {}
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        For Each item In CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems
            cmd = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO mastersubject(name,subjectpriority) VALUES(@name,@subjectpriority)", conn)
        Next
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subjectpriority", CheckedListBox1.Items.ToString())
        result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        'conn.Close()
    End With
    'End If

    If result > 0 Then

        MsgBox("Record has been saved")

    Else
        MsgBox("Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    End If

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    MsgBox(ex.Message)

Finally
    conn.Close()
End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: How did you load your combo box? The SelectedItem is an Object and when you call .ToString on an object, the default implementation is to return the fully qualified name of the object.

Comment: What is the data type of the subjectpriority column in the database?

Comment: Your for loop is creating a new command on each iteration and overwriting the value of your command variable with the exact same values.

Comment: I'm using text as a both combobox and checkedlistitem for database data type. When i click save button, the data saved into database. but the value does not appear. only shows "System.Data.DataRowView" for combobox and "System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox+ObjectCollection" for checkedlistbox.

Comment: You want a new record for each checked item in the CheckedListBox with the same name inserted in the name column each time?

Comment: Yes. I used combobox to select name, and checklistbox to select subject. I want the name and subject save in database. For an example, i choose name : John, subject : Software Engineering. So in database table for name should appear John and for subject should appear Software Engineering.

Answer (score 0):

Comments and Explanations are in line.

```
Private Sub InsertRecord()
        Dim constr As String = "server=localhost;user=root;database=login;port=3306;password=root123;SslMode=none"
        'A Using...End Using block will ensure that your data objects
        'are closed and disposed event if there is an error
        Try
            Using conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(constr)
                'You need the new keyword to create the command
                'Pass the sql query string and the connection object to the
                'constructor of the command
                'Create the command once, only the value of the subjectpriority changes
                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO mastersubject (name, subjectpriority) VALUES (@name, @subjectpriority);", conn)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@subjectpriority")
                    'Open the connection as late as possible
                    conn.Open()
                    For i = 0 To CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
                        Dim Result As Integer
                        'You are not adding a new parameter, just changing its value
                        cmd.Parameters("@subjecpriority").Value = CheckedListBox1.CheckedItems(i).ToString()
                        'the command will be executed for each item checked
                        Result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        If Result > 0 Then
                            MessageBox.Show("Record has been saved")
                        Else
                            MessageBox.Show("Error!", "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
                        End If
                    Next
                End Using 'Disposes the command
            End Using ' closes and disposes the connection
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi mary. I've try the code. but the combobox and checkedlistbox does'nt save in database. It appear the message box "Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored". What data type did you use for both name and subject priority column?

Comment: I will test further and get back to you. No time right now. Will try later tonight.

Comment: The value for combobox have been solved. I changed it into combobox.text and i can save the value into database. But for the checkbox, i still working it out.

Comment: OK, I am not too familiar with CheckedListBox or is a plain CheckBox?

Comment: I used checkedlistbox. I am not familiar with vb. Usually, i used C# language. But it is quite different with vb.